# Attempted Operation Failed Error on GetInspector.WordEditor

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

This code previews an Outlook mail.

```vb
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document '<---
Dim objMail as Object

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
Set attach = objMail.attachments
Set wordDoc = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor
```

At times `Set wordDoc = objMail.GetInspector.WordEditor` returns:

> "Attempted Operation failed."

This keeps me hanging and I don't know how to handle it.

Comment: You have an error in Dim oOutlook As Object, the you use objOutlook , but I don´t think that´s the problem. The code works for me every time...

Comment: What property or method call exactly generates an exception/error? Did you try to break the chain of property and method calls and declare them on separate lines of code?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I'd suggest breaking the chain of property and method calls and declaring them on separate lines of code. That allows to find which property or method causes the issue.

```
Dim inspector as Outlook.Inspector

Set inspector = objMail.GetInspector
Set wordDoc = inspector.WordEditor
```

Where and when do you try to get the Word editor? Is it the ItemSend event handler?

Comment: I'm using it before i have to preview the message.

Answer (score 0):

WordEditor can sometimes fail if the Inspector is not yet visible. 
Why do you need the Word object?

Comment: I have to copy an item from excel to outlook.

Comment: Why do you need the Word object for that? Why not set the HTMLBody property to a properly formatted HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Check that your Outlook application is open. In my case, the `WordEditor` could not instantiate since it was closed.

```
Sub CreateEmail()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    Dim vInspector As Object
    Set vInspector = OutMail.GetInspector

    Dim wEditor As Object
    ' THIS WILL FAIL IF OUTLOOK IS NOT OPEN
    Set wEditor = vInspector.WordEditor

    ' More VBA...
End Sub
```